# Whenever I try joining two objects, it combines the modifiers too

Tags: modeling

I have one object that has the “screw” modifier. When I join it to another object it gives that object the screw modifier too. I even tried with the Boolean modifier, but it doesn’t let me move both objects at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

If moving the objects together is the only concern, try parenting them by using Object (*Keep Transform*) option in the parenting context menu that you can open with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>. You select child object first and then the parent object. You can delete this parent-child relationship by opening Clear Parent menu by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and selecting *Clear Parent* option.